# Undefined MX records on node.js using dns.resolveMX()

Tags: node.js, dns

I am new to programming and am doing some research on mx records. I am trying to return mx records for a given domain using a very simple script and node module 'dns'. No luck! I would love some guidance to steer my first bit of code!

JS file...

```
var dns = require('dns');

console.log('loading mx records');

var url = "www.dragapp.com"



dns.resolveMx(url, function (addresses) {
    console.log('MX records:' + addresses);
});

dns.resolve(url, function (err, addresses, family) {
    console.log('DNS info: ' + addresses, family);
});
```

Terminal response...

loading mx records
DNS info: 213.129.83.231 undefined
MX records:Error: queryMx ENODATA

Answer (score 0):

The first argument of `resolveMx` callback function is `err`.

```
dns.resolveMx(url, function (err, addresses) {
    if(err)
      return console.error(err);


    console.log('MX records:' + addresses);
});
```

In your case `.resolveMx` is failing, and the error is assigned to the `address` variable, that's why you see: `Error: queryMx ENODATA`